# Save a subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

Is it possible to save (to a png) an individual subplot in a matplotlib figure? Let's say I have

```
import pyplot.matplotlib as plt
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax1.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])    
ax2.plot([3,4,5],[7,8,9])
```

Is it possible to save each of the two subplots to different files or at least copy them separately to a new figure to save them?

I am using version 1.0.0 of matplotlib on RHEL 5.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

While @Eli is quite correct that there usually isn't much of a need to do it, it is possible.  `savefig` takes a `bbox_inches` argument that can be used to selectively save only a portion of a figure to an image.

Here's a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# Make an example plot with two subplots...
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(range(10), 'b-')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(range(20), 'r^')

# Save the full figure...
fig.savefig('full_figure.png')

# Save just the portion _inside_ the second axis's boundaries
extent = ax2.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('ax2_figure.png', bbox_inches=extent)

# Pad the saved area by 10% in the x-direction and 20% in the y-direction
fig.savefig('ax2_figure_expanded.png', bbox_inches=extent.expanded(1.1, 1.2))
```

---

The full figure:
[image: Full Example Figure]

---

Area *inside* the second subplot:
[image: Inside second subplot]

---

Area around the second subplot padded by 10% in the x-direction and 20% in the y-direction:
[image: Full second subplot]

Comment: +1: Wow!  I wish I had come across these methods while trying to learn more about Matplotlib!  It would be great if the official documentation directed interested readers to these useful corners of Matplotlib, and if the presentation of the relevant concepts were more structured.  :)

Comment: A day you don't learn something new is a bad day... Well done ++

Comment: How to reduce the redundant space in top and right side of the produced figure if we use `extent.expanded()`  method? Can we precisely designate the space in each of the four side of the produce figure? That would be excellent.

Comment: Magical. I don't know you figured this out.

Comment: amazing! (sorry, stackoverflow, had to say it since this is so useful)

Comment: Amazing! To hide the black remainders of the axes lines, you can toggle `ax2.axis('off')` and `ax2.axis('on')` after saving

Comment: It appears that in the latest versions matplotlib removed dpi_scale_trans. I tried doing a Transform(figure.dpi).inverted(), but it didn't work (and to be honest it was a wild guess). Do you happen to know what's the latest way to apply your solution?

Answer (score 53):

Applying the `full_extent()` function in an answer by @Joe 3 years later from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720600), you can get exactly what the OP was looking for.  Alternatively, you can use `Axes.get_tightbbox()` which gives a little tighter bounding box

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

def full_extent(ax, pad=0.0):
    """Get the full extent of an axes, including axes labels, tick labels, and
    titles."""
    # For text objects, we need to draw the figure first, otherwise the extents
    # are undefined.
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    items = ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels() 
#    items += [ax, ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label]
    items += [ax, ax.title]
    bbox = Bbox.union([item.get_window_extent() for item in items])

    return bbox.expanded(1.0 + pad, 1.0 + pad)

# Make an example plot with two subplots...
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(range(10), 'b-')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(range(20), 'r^')

# Save the full figure...
fig.savefig('full_figure.png')

# Save just the portion _inside_ the second axis's boundaries
extent = full_extent(ax2).transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
# Alternatively,
# extent = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.renderer).transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('ax2_figure.png', bbox_inches=extent)
```

I'd post a pic but I lack the reputation points

Comment: This answer can be extended to include the text labels by adding                     items += [ax.get_xaxis().get_label(), ax.get_yaxis().get_label()]. They were cut off before I added that.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'`

Comment: @sds `fig.canvas.get_renderer()` does work.