# savefig without frames, axes, only content

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, savefig

In numpy/scipy I have an image stored in an array. I can display it, I want to save it using `savefig` *without* any borders, axes, labels, titles,... Just pure image, nothing else.

I want to avoid packages like `PyPNG` or `scipy.misc.imsave`, they are sometimes problematic (they do not always install well, only basic `savefig()` for me

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**EDIT**

Changed `aspect='normal` to `aspect='auto'` since that changed in more recent versions of matplotlib (thanks to @Luke19).

---

Assuming :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

To make a figure without the frame :

```py
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(w,h)
```

To make the content fill the whole figure

```py
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
```

Then draw your image on it :

```py
ax.imshow(your_image, aspect='auto')
fig.savefig(fname, dpi)
```

The `aspect` parameter changes the pixel size to make sure they fill the figure size specified in `fig.set_size_inches(…)`. To get a feel of how to play with this sort of things, read through [matplotlib's documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/), particularly on the subject of Axes, Axis and Artist.

Comment: nope, I still have some small transparent border, and what I want is _no border at all_, pure image

Comment: Maybe, it's because I forgot about the case where the image is not square :P. Just edited to add the `aspect` param. How's it now?

Comment: grrr, no, still the same. There is a small, transparent border around the image, few pixels on _each_ side

Comment: almost! I figured out that the border was added by `bbox_inches='tight'`. But, now the images instead of desired 24x24px are 800x600px. Still looking...

Comment: If you manually set the `w` and `h` parameters in `fig.set_size_inches(w,h)` and the `dpi` parameter in `fig.savefig(fname, dpi)` so that it result in 24px by 24px, it should work just fine. For example, `w = h = 1` and `dpi = 24`

Comment: I had to combine both this answer, and the answer below by Mostafa Pakparvar. Not only do you need to turn off the axes, but you need to set_visible to false to make sure the white space disappears. (wtf?)

Comment: Just tried this using matplotlib v2.2.2 an it worked perfectly (except that `imshow`'s syntax changed to `aspect='auto'` instead of `'normal'`).

Comment: This is the right approach. `ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])` is what makes it work.

Comment: I had to change the last line to `fig.savefig(fname, dpi=dpi)`.

Answer (score 113):

An easier solution seems to be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: This worked out great for me. Also, pad_inches can be changed to desired size easily. Thanks!

Comment: +1 worked out great for me too :)
And this is actually way simpler than the accepted answer

Comment: I still got white margins with this.

Comment: Yes, for newer versions of Matplotlib the above line seemingly results in small margins. Setting the extent manually is probably the cleanest solution:
`fig.set_size_inches((width, height))`
`extent = mpl.transforms.Bbox(((0, 0), (width, height)))`
`fig.savefig([...], bbox_inches=extent)`

Comment: I was able to update this for newer versions/remaining margins issue simply by adding transparent=True  `fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True, pad_inches=0)`

Comment: Still got axes and tickmarks and everything with this :(

Comment: This does not do anything at all. It will give you the figure with all axes and labels.

Comment: I recommend borrowing `plt.axis('off')` from another answer in combination with this one.

Answer (score 33):

You can find the bbox of the image inside the axis (using `get_window_extent`), and use the `bbox_inches` parameter to save only that portion of the image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(data)

extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', bbox_inches=extent)
```

I learned this trick from Joe Kington [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325733/save-a-subplot-in-matplotlib/4328608#4328608).

Comment: just `plt.axis('off')` helped. Other answers don't much help.

Comment: This worked pretty well.  However in my case there is still a small white border.  Any ideas of how to remove this border?

Comment: @user3731622, please try `plt.savefig('/temp/test.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0)` instead of `plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', bbox_inches=extent)`

Answer (score 23):

I've tried several options in my case, and the best solution was this:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0)
```

then save your figure with `savefig`

Comment: Out of all of this solutions, this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Actually I have tried this recently and instead of all these lines, you can use

```
plt.imsave(image_path, image)
```

Works like a charm. just one line and problem solved.

```
imsave()
```

Documentation ( https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html )

Comment: This works like a charm! It should be the best answer.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that, you can't use annotations and save it correctly in the image.

Comment: @NicolásMedina please check the question again, it is about saving only content, just image, and nothing else. Its not about saving annotations or other image data.

Answer (score 9):

I will suggest heron13 answer with a slight addition borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots) to remove the padding left after setting the bbox to tight mode, therefore:

```
axes = fig.axes()
axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying get_xaxis() and get_yaxis() don't exist. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Make an axes() object, then use ax.xaxis and ax.yaxis

Comment: Got an error saying 'list' object has no attribute 'get_xaxis'

Comment: @HaozheXie Use an Axes object, not a list of Axes...

Answer (score 9):

For anybody trying to do this in Jupyter Notebook

```
 plt.axis('off')

 spec = plt.imshow

 plt.savefig('spec',bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
```

Answer (score 8):

This one work for me

```
plt.savefig('filename',bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this code made similar the input image size without frame and axes. I combined snippets from [matehat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218887/5595995), [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219171/5595995), and [WHZW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218887/5595995):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.axis('off')
viridis = cm.get_cmap('gist_gray', 256)
plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap=viridis)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(out_file, bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
```

Runtime environment: 
  Python: 3.6.10 
  Matplotlib: 3.2.1 
  OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while doing some visualization using [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html) where I wanted to extract content of the plot without any other information. So this my approach. unutbu answer also helps me to make to work.

```
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(500, 600), dpi=1)
    axis = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off', bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off',
                    labelright='off', labelbottom='off')

     # your code goes here. e.g: I used librosa function to draw a image
    result = np.array(clip.feature_list['fft'].get_logamplitude()[0:2])
    librosa.display.specshow(result, sr=api.Clip.RATE, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', cmap='RdBu_r')


    extent = axis.get_window_extent().transformed(figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    plt.savefig((clip.filename + str("_.jpg")), format='jpg', bbox_inches=extent, pad_inches=0)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: This got me on the right track, but I had two problems: 1) I had to set the dpi to a number greater than 1 to avoid a font error in my jupyter notebook; and 2) there was still a small border so I have to manually change the extent Bbox to `extent.get_points()*np.array([[1.1],[.9]])`.

Comment: thanks for the fulfiling the answer which may help to somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

While the above answers address removing margins and padding, they did not work for me in removing labels. Here's what worked, for anyone who stumbles upon this question later:

Assuming you want a 2x2 grid of subplots from four images stored in `images`:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize = (16,12)) # or whatever image size you require
for i in range(4):
    ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    ax.axis('off')
    imshow(images[i])
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(path, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get rid of the border too, using tips here but nothing really worked.
Some fiddling about and I found that changing the faceolor gave me no border in jupyter labs (Any color resulted in getting rid of the white border). 
Hope this helps.

```
def show_num(data):
data = np.rot90(data.reshape((16,16)), k=3)
data = np.fliplr(data)
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, facecolor='white')
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a CNN model which needs simulated images as input training data. Thus, I need axes to be removed completely. I tried all presented answers and found below combination the most effective in my case for outputting a certain size figure by pixels (in my case 512*512). As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
amplitude = np.sin(time)

plt.plot(amplitude, c = 'black')

plt.savefig('no_content_data.png')
plt.close()
```

which saves below figure in a normal way with axes and no specific size:
[image]

While below codes remove everything and output figure in 512*512 pixel size:

```
pixels = 512
px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']  # pixel in inches
fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(pixels*px, pixels*px)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.]) # This is needed for fitting content to 512*512 figure frame otherwise output figure will be less than desired size
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

plt.plot(amplitude, c = 'black')

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0)
fig.subplots_adjust(top = 0.00001) # This value should be very small so that marginal axes of subplot would not overlay on the main figure
fig.subplots_adjust(right = 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0)

plt.savefig('no_content_data.png')
plt.close()
```

which gives this:
[image]