# How to remove axis, legends, and white padding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to apply colormap to an image, and write the resulting image, without using axes, labels, titles, or anything automatically added by matplotlib. Here is what I did:

```
def make_image(inputname,outputname):
    data = mpimg.imread(inputname)[:,:,0]
    fig = plt.imshow(data)
    fig.set_cmap('hot')
    fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.savefig(outputname)
```

It successfully removes the axis of the figure, but the figure saved, presents a white padding, and a frame around the actual image.

How can I remove them (at least the white padding)?

Comment: All the solutions on this question are focussed on `imshow`. If you have a scatterplot instead the following answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40727744/4124317

Comment: For subplots, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25862026/7758804)

Answer (score 642, accepted):

The [`axis('off')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) method resolves one of the problems more succinctly than separately changing each axis and border. It still leaves the white space around the border however. Adding `bbox_inches='tight'` to the `savefig` command almost gets you there; you can see in the example below that the white space left is much smaller, but still present.

Newer versions of matplotlib may require `bbox_inches=0` instead of the string `'tight'` (via @episodeyang and @kadrach)

```
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = random.random((5,5))
img = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
img.set_cmap('hot')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an `axis('off')` equivalent if I *only* want to switch off the y-axis (tick marks, tick labels, axis labels *and* the axis (frame, border, vertical lines at the left- and right-hand sides of the plot)) and keep the x-axis (same, but horizontal lines at the top and/or bottom of the plot)?

Comment: Ah, `ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)` (and the same for right/top/bottom)...

Answer (score 195):

I learned this trick from [matehat, here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8218887/190597):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_image(data, outputname, size=(1, 1), dpi=80):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(size)
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    plt.set_cmap('hot')
    ax.imshow(data, aspect='equal')
    plt.savefig(outputname, dpi=dpi)

# data = mpimg.imread(inputname)[:,:,0]
data = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3, 3))

make_image(data, '/tmp/out.png')
```

yields

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_axis_off()` is what I was looking for. `plt.axis('off')` was making my whole plot go blank.

Comment: This works when using `matplotlib.figure.Figure` rather than `pyplot`, thanks!

Answer (score 91):

Possible simplest solution:

I simply combined the method described in the question and the method from the answer by Hooked.

```
fig = plt.imshow(my_data)
plt.axis('off')
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.savefig('pict.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

After this code there is no whitespaces and no frame.

[image: No whitespaces, axes or frame]

Comment: Annoyingly, `fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)` makes everything invisible (ticks, tick labels, axis labels) *except* the axis itself (i.e. the frame/vertical lines at the left- and right-hand side of the plot)...  I was hoping to show only the x-axis this way (axis itself, ticks, labels), but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Ah, `ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)` does that (and the same for right/top/bottom)...

Answer (score 50):

No one mentioned [`imsave`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) yet, which makes this a one-liner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(10000).reshape((100, 100))
plt.imsave("/tmp/foo.png", data, format="png", cmap="hot")
```

It directly stores the image as it is, i.e. does not add any axes or border/padding.

[image]

Comment: This tip is exactly what I was looking for!   I'd still be curious to know what exactly is stored, i.e the file size isn't exactly 100*100=10000 bytes.  Rather, it is about 983 bytes.  Interesting.

Comment: @Donna The image is saved in PNG format, which compresses the data.  Hence, the resulting file size is typically less than what you would expect from just counting the pixels.

Answer (score 20):

```
plt.axis('off')
```

`plt.savefig('example.png',bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches = 0)`

gets me the borderless image.

Answer (score 13):

I found that it is all documented...

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis

My code….  "bcK" is a 512x512 image

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(bck)
plt.axis("off")   # turns off axes
plt.axis("tight")  # gets rid of white border
plt.axis("image")  # square up the image instead of filling the "figure" space
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

This should remove all padding and borders:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_visible(False)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(data)

extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
plt.savefig("../images/test.png", bbox_inches=extent)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also specify the extent of the figure to the `bbox_inches` argument. This would get rid of the white padding around the figure.

```
def make_image(inputname,outputname):
    data = mpimg.imread(inputname)[:,:,0]
    fig = plt.imshow(data)
    fig.set_cmap('hot')
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.autoscale(False)
    extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    plt.savefig(outputname, bbox_inches=extent)
```

Answer (score 9):

The upvoted answer does not work anymore. To get it to work you need 
to manually add an axis set to [0, 0, 1, 1], or remove the patch under figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=20)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
fig.add_axes(ax)
plt.imshow([[0, 1], [0.5, 0]], interpolation="nearest")
plt.axis('off')                                # same as: ax.set_axis_off()

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Alternatively, you could just remove the patch. You don't need to add a subplot in order to remove the paddings. This is simplified from [Vlady's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573601/1560241)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
fig.patch.set_visible(False)                   # turn off the patch

plt.imshow([[0, 1], [0.5, 0]], interpolation="nearest")
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig("test.png", cmap='hot')
```

This is tested with version `3.0.3` on 2019/06/19. Image see bellow:

[image]

A much simpler thing to do is to use `pyplot.imsave`. For details, [see luator's answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214623/1560241)

Answer (score 6):

I liked [ubuntu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) answer, but it was not showing explicitly how to set the size for non-square images out-of-the-box, so I modified it for easy copy-paste:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

def save_image_fix_dpi(data, dpi=100):
    shape=np.shape(data)[0:2][::-1]
    size = [float(i)/dpi for i in shape]

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(size)
    ax = plt.Axes(fig,[0,0,1,1])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax.imshow(data)
    fig.savefig('out.png', dpi=dpi)
    plt.show()
```

Saving images without border is easy whatever dpi you choose if pixel_size/dpi=size is kept.

```
data = mpimg.imread('test.png')
save_image_fix_dpi(data, dpi=100)
```

[image]

However displaying is spooky. If you choose small dpi, your image size can be larger than your screen and you get border during display. Nevertheless, this does not affect saving.

So for

```
save_image_fix_dpi(data, dpi=20)
```

The display becomes bordered (but saving works):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what finally worked for me:

ax.margins(x=0, y=0, tight=True) was the key line.

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.margins(x=0, y=0, tight=True)
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    for triangle in list_of_triangles:
        x_points = [point[0] for point in triangle]
        y_points = [point[1] for point in triangle]
        plt.fill(x_points, y_points, 'k', edgecolor='k')
    plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches=0, pad_inches=0)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
    plot.axis('off')
    ax = plot.gca()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, for certain image formats (i.e. [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF)) you can actually save the colormap in the header and most viewers will show your data with the colormap.

For saving an actual `matplotlib` image, which can be useful for adding annotations or other data to images, I've used the following solution:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=inches)
ax.matshow(data)  # or you can use also imshow
# add annotations or anything else
# The code below essentially moves your plot so that the upper
# left hand corner coincides with the upper left hand corner
# of the artist
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
# now generate a Bbox instance that is the same size as your
# single axis size (this bbox will only encompass your figure)
bbox = matplotlib.transforms.Bbox(((0, 0), inches))
# now you can save only the part of the figure with data
fig.savefig(savename, bbox_inches=bbox, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the awesome answers from everyone ...I had exactly the same problem with wanting to plot just an image with no extra padding/space etc, so was super happy to find everyone's ideas here.

Apart from image with no padding, I also wanted to be able to easily add annotations etc, beyond just a simple image plot.

So what I ended up doing was combining [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999122/9423009) with [csnemes'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49194852/9423009) to make a simple wrapper at the figure creation time.  When you use that, you don't need any changes later with imsave() or anything else:

```
def get_img_figure(image, dpi):
    """
    Create a matplotlib (figure,axes) for an image (numpy array) setup so that
        a) axes will span the entire figure (when saved no whitespace)
        b) when saved the figure will have the same x/y resolution as the array, 
           with the dpi value you pass in.

    Arguments:
        image -- numpy 2d array
        dpi -- dpi value that the figure should use

    Returns: (figure, ax) tuple from plt.subplots
    """

    # get required figure size in inches (reversed row/column order)
    inches = image.shape[1]/dpi, image.shape[0]/dpi

    # make figure with that size and a single axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=inches, dpi=dpi)

    # move axes to span entire figure area
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)

    return fig, ax
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to remove the ticks:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(15, 20))

for ax in axes:
    ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.left'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.bottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.left'] = False
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.right'] = False
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.left'] = False
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.left'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.top'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.bottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.top'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.bottom'] = False
fig = plt.figure()
```

And it removes all border and axes.

I get this from [another question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57617549/9881931).

Answer (score -1):

Surprised this didn't turn up. For plotting N images, you could use:

```
N = 5
data_array = np.random.rand(15,15,N)
plt.figure(figsize=(5*N,5))
for i in np.arange(N):
    img = data_array[:,:,i]
    plt.subplot(1,N,i+1)
    plt.imshow(img)             # Generate image
    plt.axis("off")             # Remove axes
plt.tight_layout()              # Remove white space between images
plt.show()
```

which produces something like

[image]

Comment: It didn’t turn up because that’s not the question asked in the OP. Here’s the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25862026/7758804) question with subplots. Answer’s should answer the question in the OP, not some other question.