# Turn off axes in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

I have the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cm as cm

img = mpimg.imread("lena.jpg")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0,0].imshow(img, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
axs[0,0].set_title("Rank = 512")

rank = 128
new_img = prune_matrix(rank, img)
axs[0,1].imshow(new_img, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
axs[0,1].set_title("Rank = %s" %rank)

rank = 32
new_img = prune_matrix(rank, img)
axs[1,0].imshow(new_img, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
axs[1,0].set_title("Rank = %s" %rank)

rank = 16
new_img = prune_matrix(rank, img)
axs[1,1].imshow(new_img, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
axs[1,1].set_title("Rank = %s" %rank)

plt.show()
```

However, the result is pretty ugly because of the values on the axes:

[image: 2x2 subplots]

How can I turn off axes values for all subplots simultaneously?

[How to remove axis, legends, and white padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9295026/7758804) doesn't work because I don't know how to make it work with subplots.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

- You can turn the `Axes` off by following the advice in Veedrac's comment (linking to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)) with one small modification.
- Rather than using [`plt.axis('off')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html), use [`ax.axis('off')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis.html) where `ax` is a `matplotlib.axes` object.

  - To do this, index each `Axes`, `axs[0, 0].axis('off')`, and so on for each subplot.
  - See [Native Matplotlib interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#native-matplotlib-interfaces) for the difference between `pyplot` and `Axes`.
- The code below shows the result without the `prune_matrix`, which is not available.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook  # used for matplotlib sample image

# load readily available sample image
with cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg') as image_file:
    img = plt.imread(image_file)

# read a local file
# img = mpimg.imread("file.jpg")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)
axs[0, 0].imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
axs[0, 0].set_title("Rank = 512")
axs[0, 0].axis("off")

axs[0, 1].imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
axs[0, 1].set_title("Rank = %s" % 128)
axs[0, 1].axis("off")

axs[1, 0].imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
axs[1, 0].set_title("Rank = %s" % 32)
axs[1, 0].axis("off")

axs[1, 1].imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
axs[1, 1].set_title("Rank = %s" % 16)
axs[1, 1].axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Note:** To turn off only the x or y axis you can use `set_visible()` e.g.:

```
axs[0, 0].xaxis.set_visible(False) # Hide only x axis
```

---

- Iterative approach

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)

# convert the 2d array to 1d, which removes the need to iterate through i and j
axs = axs.flat
ranks = [512, 128, 32, 16]

# iterate through each Axes with the associate rank
for ax, rank in zip(axs, ranks):

    ax.imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
    ax.set_title(f'Rank = {rank}')
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I love [Grace Hopper](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Grace-Hopper).  She is so cool!
(picosecond (at c) ~ grain of finely ground pepper) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyGtNvBZ6kk)

Answer (score 37):

Given:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

To turn off axes for all subplots:

```
for ax in axs.ravel():
    ax.set_axis_off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to set the `axison` attribute to False for each Axes as they get plotted.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread("Stewie_Griffin.png")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for i, lst in enumerate([[512, 128], [32, 16]]):
    for j, rank in enumerate(lst):
        axs[i,j].imshow(img)
        axs[i,j].set_title(f"Rank = {rank}")
        axs[i,j].axison = False           # <---- remove axis
```

[image: img1]

If you want to clearly see what is removed, you can "remove" frames and ticks separately using `Axes.set()`.

```py
        axs[i,j].set(frame_on=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

---

Finally, if you want to remove the frames and ticks after the graphs are plotted, you can loop over the list of axes in the figure itself.

```py
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.axison = False
```

---

N.B. All three methods given here (`axis('off')`, `set_axis_off()` and `axison=False`) are equivalent methods because under the hood, `axis('off')` calls `set_axis_off()`, which in turns does `axison=False`, so ultimately, they are the same.