# Generate Density Plot (of big data set) to Overlay in Google Maps

Tags: python, google-maps

I am computing geographical densities by using MySQL polynomials to create a grid over a specific location in the world.  I use geospatial indices on the grid in order to improve speed when I run the MySQL st_contains command.  It all works great but it very slow since I use a resolution of 1/1000 of a degree.  Below is a plot using Google Maps API polyline to draw the grids and the coloring the grids based on the count found using st_contains.  Since I need to do the entire world, I need to switch to less resolution for my grid.

I have tried the following Python plotting routines:  pcolormesh, imshow, heatmap, scatter, and contourf.   I have looked at also interpolating using Pythons griddata. I have not found something equivalent to plotting the polylines in Google Maps.  Any recommendations?

[Google Maps API results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcW8O.jpg)
[Python Contourf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOUbq.png)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create "density maps" using matplotlib's imshow in python and saving the image as a png. The most difficult part was discovering that there was extra white space around the png image. Thanks to a user on stackoverflow.com [Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces) I was able to remove extra white space using and to fix the origin since my figure was rotated.

```
fig = mat.imshow(Zm,origin="lower",cmap='jet') 
mat.axis('off')
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
mat.savefig('test_border.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0,edgecolor='none',transparent=True,dpi=DPI_OUTPUT)
```

To georectify the image and create my tiles I used information found at https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster?hl=en

```
gdalinfo test_border.png
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 43.0 12  44.0 11 test_border.png test_border.tif
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 test_border.tif test_border_2.tif
gdal2tiles.py -t title -g MYLICENSE -p mercator -k  test_border_2.tif test_border
```

Now, I just need to run it for the remaining non-land sections of the world...