# How to rotate image with Matplottlib without border?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an image with a white background that I would like to rotate.  The rotation, however, creates an unwanted border around the image (not the axes, but the grey outline around the pencil below).  How can I remove this border?

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

pencil = mpimg.imread('Pencil.jpg')
pencil = ndimage.rotate(pencil,105)
ax.imshow(pencil,aspect='equal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

Use `mpimg.axis('off')`

See also the matplotlib documentation:

http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean the axes, but the border that is traced around the pencil. ax.axis('off') does not remove this.

Comment: Could you post the source picture and the result of saving it with axis off but no rotation applied?