# Store 2D Array in .png format with colours

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bitmap, pypng

I wrote this Python Program to create and save a matrix (2D Array) to a .png file. The program compiles and runs without any error. Even the IMAGE.png file is created but the png file won't open. When I try to open it in MSPaint, it says:

> Cannot open image. Not a valid bitmap file or its format is not currently supported.

My objective is to create a RBG png image based on the numbers stored in the 2D Array.

Source Code:

```
    import numpy;
    import png;

    imagearray = numpy.zeros(shape=(512,512));

    /* Code to insert one '1', '2', '3' in certain locations 
       of the numpy 2D Array. Rest of the location by default stores zero '0'.*/


    f = open("IMAGE.png", 'wb');
    f.write(imagearray);
    f.close();
```

I don't understand where I went wrong as there is no error message. Please Help.

PS- I just want to save the matrix as an image file, so if you have a better and easy way of doing it in Python2.7, do suggest.

Comment: Please don't use semicolons in python, it's unnecessary. Also, your code is overindented.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because python doesn't know you're trying to save an image - all it sees is a binary file that you write an array to - `.png` is nothing more than part of the filename. A valid PNG file needs a header, which the file you create does not have

Answer (score 2):

Plot your image with matplotlib and save it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(size=(25, 25, 3))  # random 3D array
plt.imshow(a)
plt.savefig("img.png")
```

`imshow()` has various parameters of interest, amongst which `interpolation` ([examples here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html)) and `cmap` (colormap)

To remove the axes and whitespaces, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces):

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("img.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: This is generally a bad way to save an image, as it falls foul of scaling, recoloring, and borders - there are better solutions within `matplotlib` for this, in in the duplicate question

Comment: @Eric So I'll delete my answer