# Axis off with FigureCanvasTkAgg - remove frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, frame, tkinter-canvas

I am embedding `matplotlib` figure in the `tkinter` canvas, using FigureCanvasTkAgg. My wish is to remove the "border" around the elements. So to do this, in a regular Matplotlib window, we could simply use `plt.axis("off")`. However, that does not work when embedding it in FigureCanvasTkAgg.

When I do so, I get the following outcome in Tkinter:
[image]

With the following code:

```
f = plt.Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
sub1 = f.add_subplot(111) 
plt.axis('off')

# create matplotlib canvas using figure `f` and assign to widget `window`    
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.w)
    
# get canvas as tkinter's widget and `grid` in widget `window`
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan = 8)
```

Anybody knows, how to remove that black frame? Thanks!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295367/19588737