# Clean matplotlib figure without frame, margins, axes

Tags: matplotlib

I need a figure without labels, axes, and frame - just the pure data plot.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('green')
ax.plot(range(0, 10), c='red')
```

creates this plot

[image]

The problems:

1. Option removes the ticks and labels but a small black frame remains.

   ```
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
   ```
2. Option removes the background and still leaves a white margin.

   ```
    ax.axis('off') 
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
   ```
3. Option removes everything I want but also the background:

   ```
    fig.patch.set_visible(False)
   ```

Other solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610602/1864294) don't work as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the white margins with `subplots_adjust` and the frame with `spines.set_visible`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('green')
ax.plot(range(0, 10), c='red')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]