# Remove grey background borders in matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display only the plot graphic (or imshow) in matplotlib figure. I can remove the axis with pylab.axis('off') but I still have some grey borders in the figure[image]

I give an example. I want to remove all and only keep the imshow domain (and keep the zoom available).

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scipy: savefig without frames, axes, only content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content)

Comment: If `fig` is the figure you create, does `fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0)` help?

Comment: If you're talking about saving the figure with a transparent background, see @unutbu's comment. Otherwise, there has to be a background color of some sort. You can set it with `fig.set_facecolor('white')` (or whatever other color you'd like).

Comment: There does not appear to have to be a background colour of any sort: fig.set_facecolor('None') works fine.

Comment: fig.set_facecolor('None') does not remove this area ! Neither fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0)..!

Comment: True, but you want `'none'`, not `'None'` for what it's worth.  And it's still a background color, it's just the background color of the window. (Thus my comment earlier about there still being a background color. I was being overly pedantic and not helpful, though.)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you may want to reshape the figure window in order to fit the content's shape. For a squared window you can use:

```
fig = figure(figsize=(6, 6))  # width and height in inches
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.5)     # distance betweeen the axis and the figure edge
```

Make sure to keep some space for the axis labels, if you need them. If you want just to change the background color, the comment of @JoeKington is the answer.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout

Comment: It reduce it a bit. But it's still quite large for my contern...No way to remove it completely of the window ?

Comment: It reduce it a bit on the right side but I lose the centering of the display in the figure. It also make the zoom_rect tools unstabling the figure size and display position within... strange !

Comment: Can you post your code or a similar code? Maybe a image of what you want can help too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the margins() function (also an axis method):
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.margins