# How do you get the size of an image after calling matplotlib's savefig with bbox_inches='tight'?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I would like to get the dimensions of the image resulting from a call to savefig(bbox_inches='tight'). I am using bbox_inches to avoid clipping the vertical text on the X axes and the legend which I've positioned outside of the image.

`img_width, img_height = fig.get_size_inches()`

Was my first guess, however this returns the size ignoring the changes from bbox_inches=tight (i.e. the size with the legend and x axis text clipped).

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018115/matplotlib-savefig-image-size-with-bbox-inches-tight) indicates how to set the width and the hight. I would like to discover the width and height instead.

I would like to avoid the option of reading the image back off of disk and checking the width and height since this involves adding another library (e.g. PIL or OpenCV) and an unnecessary read from disk.

Comment: Looks like `plt.imread('filename.png').shape` gives the size without introducing another library. But it still involves an extra read from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, the image size is not supposed to change unlike the plotting area:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

print('Before tight_layout')
img_width, img_height = fig.get_size_inches()
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
print(f"Fig size:  ({img_width:.2f}, {img_height:.2f})")
print(f"Axes size: ({bbox.width:.2f}, {bbox.height:.2f})")

fig.set_layout_engine('tight')
fig.savefig('image.png')

print('After tight_layout')
img_width, img_height = fig.get_size_inches()
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
print(f"Fig size:  ({img_width:.2f}, {img_height:.2f})")
print(f"Axes size: ({bbox.width:.2f}, {bbox.height:.2f})")

plt.close()
```

Output:

```
Before tight_layout
Fig size:  (6.40, 4.80)
Axes size: (4.96, 3.70)
After tight_layout
Fig size:  (6.40, 4.80)
Axes size: (5.78, 4.26)
```

Check:

```
arr_height, arr_width, _ = plt.imread('image.png').shape
print(f"Image size: ({arr_width / fig.dpi:.2f}, {arr_height / fig.dpi:.2f})")

# Output
Image size: (6.40, 4.80)
```

Comment: Brilliant @Corralien. `bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())` was what I was after.