# Make edges start from outside the node in Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a weighted circular layout plot.
I wanted to make edges start from the outside of the node, but cannot find a way to do so. I tried setting alpha=1, but that didn't give me the desired outcome.
The image below displays what I'm getting right now

[image]

This is the following code I have for nodes right now:

```
for n in G.nodes():
    if n in set1:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#7a8eff'
    elif n in set2:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#eb2c30'
    elif n in set3:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#7300ff'
    else:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#730a15'

colors = [node[1]['color'] for node in G.nodes(data=True)]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1000, node_color=colors)


# edges
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge
    rad = 0.25
    node_color_dict = dict(G.nodes(data='color'))
    if node_color_dict[source] == node_color_dict[target]:
        arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                        arrowstyle="-",
                        color='blue',
                        connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                        linestyle= '-',
                        alpha=0.45)
        ax.annotate("",
                    xy=pos[source],
                    xytext=pos[target],
                    arrowprops=arrowprops
                   )
    else:
        arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                        arrowstyle="-",
                        color='purple',
                        connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                        linestyle= '-',
                        alpha=0.45)
        ax.annotate("",
                    xy=pos[source],
                    xytext=pos[target],
                    arrowprops=arrowprops
                   )
# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=11, font_family="monospace", font_color='white', font_weight='bold', alpha=1.0)
```

Comment: We need the full code to help you, if I only use `nx.draw`, I could not reproduce the issue. I guess you first draw nodes and then the edges. Changing this order will probably resolve the issue. If you add a minimal reproducible example, it's way easier to help you.

Comment: @Sparky05 i added more code, hope it's helpful

Comment: In that case adding `zorder` to the arrowprops should solve your issue. I've extended the code example below

Comment: @Sparky05 it works, but the only issue i'm facing is that now the node labels don't show up. i'm simply using: `nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=11, font_family="monospace", font_color='white', font_weight='bold')` to draw labels

Comment: I've now build a complete example with edges, nodes, and node labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A full example, which produces the desired result:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl


G = nx.karate_club_graph()
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

set1 = set(node for node in G if G.nodes[node]["club"] == "Mr. Hi")
set2 = set(node for node in G if G.nodes[node]["club"] != "Mr. Hi")

for n in G.nodes():
    if n in set1:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#7a8eff'
    elif n in set2:
        G.nodes[n]['color'] = '#eb2c30'

for u, v in G.edges():
    G.edges[(u,v)]["weight"] = 1

colors = [node[1]['color'] for node in G.nodes(data=True)]
nodes_draw = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1000, node_color=colors)

ax = pl.gca()

# draw in the order, edges, nodes, node labels
zorder_edges = 3
zorder_nodes = 4
zorder_node_labels = 5

# edges
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge
    rad = 0.25
    node_color_dict = dict(G.nodes(data='color'))
    if node_color_dict[source] == node_color_dict[target]:
        arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                        arrowstyle="-",
                        color='blue',
                        connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                        linestyle= '-',
                        #alpha=0.45,
                        zorder=zorder_edges,
                        )
        ax.annotate("",
                    xy=pos[source],
                    xytext=pos[target],
                    arrowprops=arrowprops
                   )
    else:
        arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                        arrowstyle="-",
                        color='purple',
                        connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                        linestyle= '-',
                        #alpha=0.45,
                        zorder=zorder_edges,
                        )
        ax.annotate("",
                    xy=pos[source],
                    xytext=pos[target],
                    arrowprops=arrowprops
                   )
# labels
node_labels_dict = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=11, font_family="monospace", font_color='white', font_weight='bold',
                                           #alpha=1.0
                                           )

nodes_draw.set_zorder(zorder_nodes)
for node_labels_draw in node_labels_dict.values():
    node_labels_draw.set_zorder(zorder_node_labels)

pl.axis("off")
# do don't cut off nodes
ax.set_xlim([1.1*x for x in ax.get_xlim()])
ax.set_ylim([1.1*y for y in ax.get_ylim()])
pl.show()
```

The result:

[image: Visualization of the resulting network]

### Background

You can change the [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) of the created `matplotlib` objects:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
# an example graph with string (names) as nodes
g = nx.karate_club_graph()
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(g)

e = nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos=pos, )
n = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos=pos, )

e.set_zorder(5) 
n.set_zorder(10)
pl.show()
```

In case you use some advanced edge drawing, add the `zorder` parameter to the arrowprops parameter ([all possible parameters](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch)) of [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html), e.g.

```
arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                        arrowstyle="-",
                        color='blue',
                        connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                        linestyle= '-',
                        alpha=0.45,
                        zorder=0)
```

I've included [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61521950/11339311) to avoid cutting nodes at the border.