# Matplotlib force figure size of output image

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm creating a matplotlib figure. And I want the size (or at least the aspect ratio) of the output image to be consistent.
It seems like using `figsize` changes the contained figure but not the image.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
ax.barh([0,1,2],[1,5,3])
ax.set_yticks([0,1,2])
ax.set_yticklabels(['a','b','c'])
```

Creates the following:
[image]

While a change in the `ticklabels` enlarges the image

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
ax.barh([0,1,2],[1,5,3])
ax.set_yticks([0,1,2])
ax.set_yticklabels(['a really really really really really really long name','b','c'])
```

[image]

I wish for the opposite - keep the output the same size and have the chart change as needed.

Comment: Can you try adding the following: `fig.canvas.layout.width = '9in'` and `fig.canvas.layout.height= '9in'` and see if it works

Comment: `AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'layout'`

Comment: I remove `layout` using only `fig.canvas.width = '9in'
fig.canvas.height = '9in'` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was able to devise the following solution. It does the trick somewhat although I do not claim it to be the best solution. The idea is the following:

1. Get the width of the y-ticklabels **in inches** (I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306776/4932316) method)
2. Extract the maximum width i.e. for the longest tick-label
3. Reset the figure size at the end using width = 9-max(label width)

---

```
# Rest of your code

fig.canvas.draw()

# Get the labels' widths in inches
label_widths = [item.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()).width 
                for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]

Since the original size was 9 inches by 9 inches, rescale the size
fig.set_size_inches((9-max(label_widths)), 9)
```

[image]