# Is it possible to automatically scale the figure size, but keep the plot size constant in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to create multiple bar plots using the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
plt.barh(y=y, width=width, height=0.5)
plt.yticks(y, labels)
plt.xlabel("Contribution")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Since the length of my y-ticks labels can vary, the plot can get squeezed together as in the case below:

[image: squeezed matplotlib plot]

In other cases the plot looks fine:

[image]

Now, I was wondering, if there is an option in `matplotlib` to keep the plot size constant, but scale the figure size automatically (in horizontal direction)? My goal is that the plot size stays always the same, independent of the y-label length (because they vary inbetween plots). Thank you!

Comment: It is happening in your current case that figure (whole image) is of constant size and your axes are getting squeezed. Maybe I just understand you incorrectly but aren't you wanting to have fixed size axes (plot) and then expand whole figure to be able to fit in all axes and labels?

Comment: @RomanPavelka Yes, you are right. I would like that the plot size stays always the same (or as you said fixed size axes) and automatically expand the figure to fit all labels

Comment: You could try using `set_box_aspect`, so that the aspect ratio of the two axes is always a fixed value https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect

Comment: These two sources should help you, but I would just keep figsize large enough for all cases... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306510/determine-matplotlib-axis-size-in-pixels https://stackabuse.com/change-figure-size-in-matplotlib/

Comment: My comment about using `set_box_aspect` will work to keep the axes boxes the same size, but unfortunately it will just cause the tick mark text to get truncated by the figure boundary, so probably isn't what your looking for.