# Matplotlib shrink figure to size of axes, or otherwise match its aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been using Cartopy to plot data using `'equal'` aspect, resulting in all manner of non-square Axes sizes. These usually look OK in Jupyter notebooks, but when saving the images (or when doing more complicated operations like adding colorbars), the resulting Figures are often huge, with a lot of blank space around the Axes plotting area. They also look bad when using `%matplotlib widget`. An example is provided below.

[image: Example of image with undesirable padding]

It seems that the *figure* in this case is too big in at least one dimension. I would like to remove that extra space in the final output figure, without shrinking the size of the plotting area itself.

I know that I can adjust the figure size itself with `.set_figwidth` and `.set_figheight`, as well as setting `figsize=` upon creation. But I don't know how to figure out the correct dimensions to shrink the figure without shrinking the axes, and I haven't seen any way to do this automatically. What's the correct solution? I would like to avoid manually editing my images after creating them!

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306776/13636407

Comment: @paime I think that answers the question, yes! I will try it and post a self-answer if it works. I am sure I am not the first person to have this question, and I never came across the answer you posted after searching for a long time, due to the limited scope of the question it addresses.