# Save Matplotlib figure as TIFF

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

Does anyone know how to save a Matplotlib figure as *.tiff? It seems that this format is not supported in Python, while the journals are quite often ask for that format.

I am adding some minimal code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fig setup
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

# draw a surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-1,2), range(-1,2))
zz = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='#c8c8c8', alpha=0.3)
ax.plot_surface(xx, zz, yy, color='#b6b6ff', alpha=0.2)

# draw a point
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0], color='b', s=200)
```

This works:

```
fig.savefig('3dPlot.pdf')
```

But this does not:

```
fig.savefig('3dPlot.tif')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save raw data as tif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673619/save-raw-data-as-tif)

Comment: Unfortunately, they do ask for tiff-s. I know it's weird. Also, I did not work with it.

Comment: If you don't need accurate colour reproduction you could simply save as png and convert the png file to tiff. I've done that before.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  Not every plot is a raw image.  For example, if we start with a simple `plot(x, y)`, it is not clear at all how one could save that as `tif` with PIL/Pillow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is great! Thanks ot [Martin Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985733/martin-evans).
However, for those who would like to make it happen in `Python3.x`, small fixes (since `cStringIO` module is not available; and I would rather use `BytesIO`)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# fig setup
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

# draw a point
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0], color='b', s=200)

# save figure
# (1) save the image in memory in PNG format
png1 = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(png1, format='png')

# (2) load this image into PIL
png2 = Image.open(png1)

# (3) save as TIFF
png2.save('3dPlot.tiff')
png1.close()
```

Comment: What if I need to save a bar graph as a tiff image ? What should I assign to 'fig' ?

Answer (score 19):

As a workaround, there would be nothing to stop you using the Python PIL package to save your image in TIFF format:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
import io

# fig setup
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

# draw a surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-1,2), range(-1,2))
zz = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='#c8c8c8', alpha=0.3)
ax.plot_surface(xx, zz, yy, color='#b6b6ff', alpha=0.2)

# draw a point
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0], color='b', s=200)

#fig.savefig('3dPlot.pdf')

# Save the image in memory in PNG format
png1 = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(png1, format="png")

# Load this image into PIL
png2 = Image.open(png1)

# Save as TIFF
png2.save("3dPlot.tiff")
png1.close()
```

---

If Python 2.x is being used, use `cStringIO` instead of `BytesIO` as follows:

```
import cStringIO

# Replace the BytesIO() call with
png1 = cStringIO.StringIO()
```

Answer (score 8):

[Matplotlib does support tif since version 1.1](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/852b41c1e59969e5e627b38fd392e926e13442ca) but the support is optional and not obvious. As long as you have [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) installed, you can save to tif like you can save to any other format. Thus your example would simply be:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL # not necessary but mustn't fail

# fig setup
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.axes.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

# draw a surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-1,2), range(-1,2))
zz = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='#c8c8c8', alpha=0.3)
ax.plot_surface(xx, zz, yy, color='#b6b6ff', alpha=0.2)

# draw a point
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0], color='b', s=200)

fig.savefig('3dPlot.tif')
```

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do is install **Pillow** .
Then you can use just this:

```
fig.savefig('3dPlot.tiff')
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest path to achieve TIFF output from matplotlib (and Pillow).