# Remove whitespace in matplotlib when plotting on top of image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried many methods, but none seem to work. Everywhere I look people say set `bbox_inches='tight'` but that doesn't seem to work.

Basically my goal is to plot some points on top of the image in pixel coordinates and then save it without the any whitespace around the border. My code currently looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
img = plt.imread('myimage.jpg')
ymax, xmax, _ = img.shape
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0,xmax,ymax,0]) # switch to pixel coords
plt.plot([100,200,300],[100,200,300],'ro')
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0,xmax,ymax,0]) # recenter plot
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('out.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

But my saved image still have a white border around it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Because matplotlib is pretty much the same as matlab in terms of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `bbox_inches='tight'` option tries to fit your figure with axis ticks in mind. In order to avoid that you can provide the the actual extent of the figure to `plt.savefig` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('myimage.jpg')

ymax, xmax, _ = img.shape
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0,xmax,ymax,0]) # switch to pixel coords
plt.plot([100,200,300],[100,200,300],'ro')
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0,xmax,ymax,0]) # recenter plot
plt.axis('off')

# get figure and axis handle 
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
# get axis extent
extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
plt.savefig('out.jpg', bbox_inches=extent)
```

If, for some reason, you want to add a small white edge to your figure, you can still do that; just expand the extent as follow

```
extent2 = extent.expanded(1.01, 1.01)
plt.savefig('out.jpg', bbox_inches=extent2)
```

An other option will be to get-rid off the axis boundary completely using  [matehat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content/8218887#8218887) suggestion.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = plt.imread('myimage.jpg')
ymax, xmax, _ = img.shape
my_dpi = 80.
my_figsize = [xmax/my_dpi, ymax/my_dpi]
fig  = plt.figure(figsize=my_figsize, dpi=my_dpi)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

h_im = ax.imshow(img, aspect = 'equal', extent=[0,xmax,ymax,0])
plt.plot([100,200,300],[100,200,300],'ro')
plt.axis(h_im.get_extent())
plt.savefig('out.jpg', dpi = my_dpi)
```

Although the final image has the original image size there is a sub-pixle difference between the two images. The figure below shows the difference between the `myimage.jpg` and `out.jpg`.

[image: Difference between original image and output image]

Comment: This changes the aspect ratio of the output though. I want the saved image to be the same size as the input image. How would I do that?

Comment: Modified the answer.