# matplotlib - How to save an array as image with overlayed text?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a 2D array that I need to save as a `png`. I also need to add a text label to the image. So far, I have tried two approaches, none of which is optimal:

- I use the `matplotlib.image` module to save the array directly as an image:

  ```
  matplotlib.image.imsave(FILENAME, ARRAY, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
  ```

  However I am unable to add text using that command. I could use `PIL` to read and edit after saving the raw images, but the I/O cost on a large data set would be unacceptable.
- I use the `pyplot` interface to convert the array to a figure and then add a legend. However when I save it as a file, there is unnecessary whitespace. I have tried turning axes off, setting padding to 0 etc., but there is always some whitespace margin I cannot get rid of:

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.imshow(ARRAY, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
  plt.axis('off') 
  plt.savefig(FILENAME, dpi=100, pad_inches=0.0, bbox_inches='tight')
  ```

Is there a way to generate an image from a 2D array, overlay text, and save as .png speedily with no whitespace? Preferably a solution using matplotlib/PIL, but if there's anything better out there, I can look into it.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using an object oriented approach from the start:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, tight_layout=True, frameon=False, figsize=(resolution/100.,resolution/100.)) # dpi & figsize of my choosing
fig.figimage(ARRAY, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
fig.text(X,Y,TEXT, size='medium', backgroundcolor='white', alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig(FILENAME)
plt.close(fig)
```

Additional documentation for the `figure` class can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html).

Note: For sizing figures, I found this relationship useful:
*size in inches = resolution in pixels / DPI*