# Save an image (only content, without axes or anything else) to a file using Matloptlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spectrogram, savefig

I'd like to obtain a spectrogram out of a wav file and then save it to a png, but I need just the content of the image (not axes or anything else). I came across these questions
[Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)
[scipy: savefig without frames, axes, only content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content)
I've also read [the Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) but it seems useless and so either answers to questions above are outdated or I'm doing something wrong because simple

`plt.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)`

does not do what I want to achieve. Initially I tried to follow [this guide](http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html?i=1) but the code crashes. Then I tried [this approach](https://vkolachalama.blogspot.com/2016/08/convert-wav-file-to-spectrogram-in.html), but since it's outdated I modified it a little:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

def graph_spectrogram(wav_file):
    rate, data = wavfile.read(wav_file)
    pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(x=data, Fs=rate, noverlap=384, NFFT=512)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('sp_xyz.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, frameon='false')

if __name__ == '__main__': # Main function
    graph_spectrogram('...')
```

This is what I got:
[image]
Maybe it's not visible, but there's a white border around the content (from the biggest to the smallest): left, bottom, top, right. I want the same image but just the content without anything else. How can I achieve that? I use python 3.6 and Matplotlib 2.0.2.

Comment: Try `pad_inches=0.0` as parameter in `plt.savefig(...)`

Comment: No, unfortunately. I've seen this in comments to the linked questions and I've tried it earlier but it changes nothing.

Comment: I've just seen you can give a negative value to `pad_inches` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib) answer comment, have you tried that?

Comment: I've seen that question too, but I didn't tried that, wait a sec

Comment: No, it's not that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html):

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
```

In this case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

def graph_spectrogram(wav_file):
    rate, data = wavfile.read(wav_file)
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)
    ax.axis('off')
    pxx, freqs, bins, im = ax.specgram(x=data, Fs=rate, noverlap=384, NFFT=512)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig('sp_xyz.png', dpi=300, frameon='false')

if __name__ == '__main__': # Main function
    graph_spectrogram('...')
```

Comment: Now I don't have any content at all, although the image is 1920 x 1440 px

Comment: The thing was that I used `plt.specgram` instead of `ax.specgram`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

May be helpful for someone who use librosa latest versions.

You can add **transparent=True** to the *plt.savefig()* function to set transparent background. But the problem is still x and y axis information are visible. Hens, you need to remove axis details using **ax.set_axis_off()**

You can remove right side color-bar by commenting out *plt.colorbar()*

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.set_cmap('hot')
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(S_full[:, idx], ref=np.max), y_axis='log', x_axis='time',sr=sr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig(f'{args["output"]}/{name}_{i}.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0.0 )
```

**Please click images to check differences**

**When nothing is changed(Default)**
[image: save image without changing anything]

**When the axis informations are off** Using *ax.set_axis_off()*

Here, this image doesn't have axis info but white background is there.
[image: When axis off]

**When enabling transparent** using *transparent= True*

Here, this image doesn't have white background but axis info is there.
[image]

**With axis info are off and enabling transparent**

This image doesn't have either white background or axis info
[image: Axis info is off and enable transparent]

**You may not see the exact differences since images might be changed when uploading.**