# How to save a figure without the borders/margins in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know there is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content). However, I tried all of the possible solutions posted there and absolutely none of them worked for me. This is why I'm creating this question.

This is what I have:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile

sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read('audio-mono-70.wav')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,1), dpi=500, frameon=False)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0,0,1,1])
ax.set_facecolor((0.169,0.169,0.169))
ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=700000)
fig.add_axes(ax)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False,
                top=False, left=False, right=False,
                labelbottom=False, labeltop=False,
                labelright=False, labelleft=False)
plt.plot(samples)
plt.savefig('samples.png')
```

With this, I'm getting everything I want, except for the presence of those margins. Here it is.

[image]

And what I want is something like this. I modified this image manually just to show you what I need. I need the image to not have those small margins. I am setting the x limits because I want the plot to reach the left and right borders of the image, but that black margin is getting in the way.

[image]

Using `bbox_inches='tight'` and `pad_inches=0`, seems to not work in newer versions of matplotlib, and using `plt.savefig(fname, bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0)` didn't work for me either. I get the exact same result. Also tried `extent = mpl.transforms.Bbox(((0, 0), (width, height)))` and then `bbox_inches=extent`, but still nothing. None of those in that post.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Added code to create the exact same array with which the plot was created.

Find the exact same audio [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4r995speeacjbb/audio-mono-70.wav?dl=0)

**EDIT 2**

The rgb values for the `ax.set_facecolor()` originally set it to black, but the images had gray facecolor. Fixed in this edit.

Comment: `plt.savefig('samples.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)`An image with no correct margins has been saved. My environment is 'matplotlib:3.3.0'.

Comment: @r-beginners I don't really understand. Is that an error you got? I didn't get an error with that, just the same image with the small margins.

Comment: @TheSprinter can you post reproducible example that will create similar image?

Comment: No errors occurred and the image was saved with no margins.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thanks for your comment. The code serves perfectly as reproducible example to see the margins. However, see edit 1 if you want to plot the exact same image.

Comment: @r-beginners You sure? Did you look closely? I downloaded from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib, which is the same version.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Well, yes, I realized the `samples` array wasn't created in the orignal post.

Comment: Using the updated sample data, the images created and saved as graphs do indeed show extra margins at both ends. Fixing it to `dpi=384` removes the margins. This setting is manual: `dpi=500
may have been too big.

Comment: @r-beginners Tried with `dpi=384` but still got the same margin. Two questions: Where did that number (384) come from? How does the resolution of the image affect whether it has margins or not?

Comment: I just matched it to the screen resolution, which is 96 DPI, so I just tripled it. This doesn't make a lot of sense, you might want to try adjusting the DPI in various ways.

Comment: @r-beginners Yeah, it doesn't. I might get it to work in my machine, but I need it to work anywhere, with any screen resolution; so what I really need is some function or method that will effectively remove that margin.

Comment: I think I gave you some extra information. I was able to achieve this by manually changing the DPI value. So you can try that too and if the issue doesn't resolve itself, it's another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help somewhere else and these borders/margins are called spines.

They are deleted in the following way, in my case:

```py
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
```