# How to save a manipulated numpy array (annotated image) as an image, using python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, data-visualization

I have loaded an image, converted it to an array and annotated it (56.01). Now I want to save it back as an image.
How can I do that?

With this code, the image is annotated. But I want to remove the axes and save it as an image.

```
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ax=plt.gca()

# load image as pixel array
data = image.imread('yellow.jpg')

ax.annotate('56.05',xy=(1000, 500), xycoords='data')


# display the array of pixels as an image
plt.imshow(data)
plt.savefig('imagenet1.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 1000)
plt.show()
```

ANNOTATED ARRAY

[image]

I WANT THIS, BUT THE ANNOTATION IS NOT HERE
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy: savefig without frames, axes, only content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content)

Comment: Would you like to store the annotation on the image, or as metadata?

Comment: The annotation on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to annotate *after* calling `imshow`, and hide the x and y axes. Alternatively you could plot things in whatever order you want as long as you provided them with a logical `zorder` parameter.

```
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# load image as pixel array
data = image.imread('yellow.jpg')

# display the array of pixels as an image
ax.imshow(data)
ax.annotate('56.05', xy=(1000, 500), xycoords='data')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('imagenet1.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=1000)
fig.show()
```