# Matplotlib get clean plot (remove all decorations)

Tags: python, matplotlib

As a reference, same question but for `imshow()`: [Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

It is not obvious in embedded image on selected answer that there are fat white margins around the plot, as stackoverflow page background is white.

The following answer by @unutbu works for `imshow()` but not for general `plot()`. Also `aspect='normal` is deprecated since version 1.2.

So how to save `plot()` as image, without any decorations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ax.set_axis_off()`, or equivalently, `ax.axis('off')` toggles the axis lines and labels off. To remove more whitespace, you could use

```
fig.savefig('/tmp/tight.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

Or [to remove all whitespace up to the axis' boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328608/190597), use

```
extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('/tmp/extent.png', bbox_inches=extent)
```

These commands will work equally well with either `ax.imshow(data)` or `ax.plot(data)`.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3, 3))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
ax.axis('off')
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328608/190597 (Joe Kington)
# Save just the portion _inside_ the axis's boundaries
extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('/tmp/extent.png', bbox_inches=extent)
fig.savefig('/tmp/tight.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

extent.png (504x392):

[image]

tight.png (521x414):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that @unutbu's answer does work with `plot()` too, if we remove `aspect='normal'` from `plot()` directive:

```
data = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3, 3))
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(1, 1)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.plot(data)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

But, I still wonder if all this is really necessary to get clean plot?
Shouldn't be there obvious argument to `savefig()` that can handle this?