# Is there a way to get display/save the dendrograms and heatmap created using seaborn.clustermap in Python?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, dendrogram

I am using seaborn.clustermap to create an ordered heatmap.  I would like to be able to save both of the dendrograms and the heatmap separately.  Is there a way to separate the three.

My code for creating the heatmap/dendrogram combination is as follows.

```
sns.clustermap(datadissimilarity, method='average', figsize=(40,40))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`sns.clustermap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) returns a 'clustergrid' which contains the subplots as 'axes': `g.ax_col_dendrogram`, `g.ax_row_dendrogram,` g.ax_heatmap`,` g.ax_col_colors`,` g.ax_row_colors`and`g.ax_cbar`.

You can use these axes to calculate a bounding box of the desired areas. See also the second answer of [Save a subplot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325733/save-a-subplot-in-matplotlib) about how to combine areas to select an exact area of interest.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)

fig = g.fig
for ax, filename in zip([g.ax_col_dendrogram, g.ax_row_dendrogram, g.ax_heatmap],
                        ['col_dendrogram', 'row_dendrogram', 'heatmap']):
    extent = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.renderer).transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    fig.savefig(f'{filename}.png', bbox_inches=extent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save only part of the figure [using `bbox_inches=`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) in the call to `g.savefig()`.

The dendrograms and the heatmaps are located in separates `Axes` objects, that you can access using `g.ax_row_dendrogram`, `g.ax_col_dendrogram`, and `g.ax_heatmap`. You can use the figure transforms to get their position in inches to pass to `bbox_inches`.

```py
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)

for ax,name in zip([g.ax_heatmap, g.ax_col_dendrogram, g.ax_row_dendrogram],
                   ['heatmap.png','col_dendrogram.png','row_dendrogram.png']):
    bbox = ax.get_window_extent()
    inches = g.fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted().transform_bbox(bbox)
    g.savefig(name, bbox_inches=inches)
```

Comment: This question was 15 hours old, and you answer it just 1 minute earlier ....

Comment: Weird! and our answers are almost identical. Although yours is better since it doesnt cut off the labels of the heatmap. +1